# How to find the limsup and liminf of a sequence of intervals

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $A_n$ = ( $\frac{-1}{n}, 1+\frac{n-1}{n}$]

How would you determine the limsup $A_n$ and liminf $A_n$?

I am trying to use the follow definitions for limsup and liminf respectively:
$$
\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n
$$

$$
\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n\ge N} A_n
$$

I was thinking the limsup $A_n$ would be the interval contained in all $A_n$ (the null set), and liminf $A_n$ would be the interval contained in at least one $A_n$, (-1,2]. This is based off my understanding of lim sup/inf and im hoping someone can explain this using the definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $A_n=\left(-\frac1n,2-\frac1n\right]=-\frac1n+(-1,2]$. So, if $N\in\mathbb N$,$$\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}A_n=\left(-\frac1N,2\right)$$and therefore$$\limsup_nA_n=\bigcap_{N\in\mathbb N}\left(-\frac1N,2\right)=[0,2).$$On the other hand, if $N\in\mathbb N$,$$\bigcap_{n\geqslant N}A_n=\left[0,2-\frac1N\right]$$and therefore$$\liminf_n=\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb N}\left[0,2-\frac1N\right]=[0,2)$$too.

Comment: I don't really follow the logic, can you explain the steps on how you got the union of An, an also lim sup An = [0,2).

Comment: @BobDoe Since I provided a detailed answer, it's up to you to tell me which passage were you unable to understand.

Comment: How did you get U A_n = (-1/N,2), and ∩(-1/N,2) = [0,2)

Comment: The union of all $A_n$'s is$$\left(-\frac1N,2-\frac1N\right]\cup\left(-\frac1{N+1},2-\frac1{N+1}\right]\cup\left(-\frac1{N+1},2-\frac1{N+1}\right]\cup\cdots=\left(-\frac1N,2\right).$$On the other hand, which numbers belong to all intervals of the form $\left(-\frac1N,2\right)$? It should be clear that the answer is $[0,2)$.